# Expected waiting time - simplified

Tags: statistics, average

I need some assistance with a calculation I'm trying to do.

I have access to surgery waiting times data (date arrived, date completed) and I want to figure out the expected waiting time for a new patient - this should take into account the number of patients already waiting and those who have completed (I think).

I've tried looking at the average time to wait for the past three hours but this doesn't seem the right way to do it (too simple I think).

I've also thought about perhaps looking at the average wait time for the same day of the week for a previous week...would that be sensible?

There are so many variables to consider but I need something relatively simple...

Comment: I suspect this question might get better answers at stats.stackexchange.com than here. $\qquad$